# How do I store data read in from a CSV into a collection

Tags: java, arrays, list, netbeans, collections

I have been tasked with creating a game called Taboo. It consists of a main word and 3 banned words. The aim of the game is for the words to display on the screen and the user then has to describe the main word without using the word itself or the banned words.

I have so far been able to read in the data that I have stored in a CSV and have it so that when I choose to output BannedWords, it does so. The problem now, is that when it outputs either MainWord or BannedWord1, etc... it outputs the data for each record in the CSV.

Below is the data from my CSV (it is just a test with few records so that when it works I can introduce the rest).

Tree,Brown,Green,Nature

Lake,Blue,Water,Wet

Apple,Green,Fruit,Healthy

---

If I chose to output MainWord, which is the first word, it outputs like this:

Tree

Lake

Apple

---

I need to somehow store the data being read in from the CSV **individually** in a collection so that when I need to use them, they output properly and they in a such a way that I can display them later on in a GUI JLabel.

It might also be useful to note that I am using NetBeans so I am able to use any of the built in functions as well.

```
public class Card 
{
    private String sMainWord;
    private String sBannedWord1;
    private String sBannedWord2;
    private String sBannedWord3;

    public Card(String sMW, String sBW1, String sBW2,String sBW3)
    {
        sMainWord = sMW;
        sBannedWord1 = sBW1;
        sBannedWord2 = sBW2;
        sBannedWord3 = sBW3;
    }

    public void setsMainWord(String sMW)
    {
        sMainWord = sMW;
    }

    public String getsMainWord()
    {
        return sMainWord;
    }

    public void setsBannedWord1(String sBW1)
    {
        sBannedWord1 = sBW1;
    }

    public String getsBannedWord1()
    {
        return sBannedWord1;
    }

    public void setsBannedWord2(String sBW2)
    {
       sBannedWord2 = sBW2; 
    }

    public String getsBannedWord2()
    {
        return sBannedWord2;
    }

    public void setsBannedWord3(String sBW3)
    {
        sBannedWord3 = sBW3;
    }

    public String getsBannedWord3()
    {
        return sBannedWord3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        String fileNameDefined = "/Users/student/NetBeansProjects/TabooGameComplete/CSData.csv";
        File file = new File(fileNameDefined);

         try
        {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);


            while(inputStream.hasNext() != false)
            {

                String TabooCardWords = inputStream.nextLine();
                String[] information = TabooCardWords.split(",");

                String MainWord = information[0];
                String BannedWord1 = information[1];
                String BannedWord2 = information[2];
                String BannedWord3 = information[3];

                Card TBC = new Card (MainWord, BannedWord1, BannedWord2, BannedWord3);


                System.out.println("*" + BannedWord1 + "*");
            }


        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use Commons CSV to handle your CSV needs. It's easy to use and would make your life a lot simpler.

Comment: I'm guessing this a low level course question, meaning that standard/external libraries don't tend to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the output statement in the loop that generates your `Card`s so that everytime a card is created, you are outputting its `BannedWord1`.  As you are creating them all, one after another, they will all output, one after another.

i.e.

```
//For each line in file
while(inputStream.hasNext() != false)
{
  //Create Card
  //Output BannedWord1 used to create Card
}
```

If you want to output one element of one `Card`, you will need to keep the `Card` objects you create to be used outside the loop:-

```
Card[] cards = new Cards[3];
int i=0;
//For each line in file
while(inputStream.hasNext() != false)
{
  //Create Card
  cards[i++] = newlyCreatedCardObject;  //Store card object for later
  //Output BannedWord1 used to create Card
}

//Output BannedWord1 from the Card created from the second line
System.out.println(cards[1].getsBannedWord1());
```

**Additional Point**

By convention, java variables begin with lowercase letters and classes with uppercase, so this can be confusing

```
String TabooCardWords;  //Should really be 'tabooCardWords'
...
String MainWord = information[0];    //-> 'mainWord'
String BannedWord1 = information[1]; //-> 'bannedWord1'
String BannedWord2 = information[2]; //-> 'bannedWord2'
String BannedWord3 = information[3]; //-> 'bannedWord3'
```

Comment: thank you so much, very useful and very quick. Thanks again